# React Native/Node API: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, cors, fetch-api

I am having an issue with my react native app interacting with my Node API.
When I try to post data to update some values in the database through node (which then goes to a stored procedure), I get a 500 - *Can't set headers after they are sent* in Node.

Everything I can find says that this could be due to sending responses twice.  I don't think this is the case here.  I've tested in postman and things work fine, it returns a status of 200 with the correct returned data.

I am trying to post data to the API like so:

```
  const myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');


  fetch(`http://localhost:3000/user/preferences`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: myHeaders,
      mode: 'cors',
      cache: 'default',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        id: '1',
        minage: this.state.minageValue,
        maxage: this.state.maxageValue
      })
  })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(body => console.log(body))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I am receiving it on the API side and passing the data to a stored procedure with this:

```
function updatePreferences(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req);
    var userid = req.body[0].id;
    var minage = req.body[0].minage;
    var maxage = req.body[0].maxage;

    db.func('___spsavepreferences', [userid, minage, maxage])
        .then(function(data){
            res.status(200)
                .json({
                    status: 'success',
                    preferences: data
                });
        });
}
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Don't know if this tells me anything, but I have logged the error message to the console:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:504:11)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:511:3)
at ServerResponse.header (/Users/user/Projects/Project_node/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:730:10)
POST /user/preferences 500 410.809 ms - 189
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/user/Projects/Project_node/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at done (/Users/user/Projects/Project_node/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:967:10)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/Users/user/Projects/Project_node/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:374:12)
    at View.exports.__express [as engine] (/Users/user/Projects/Project_node/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:417:11)
    at View.render (/Users/user/Projects/Project_node/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:128:8)
    at tryRender (/Users/user/Projects/Project_node/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/Users/user/Projects/Project_node/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/user/Projects/Project_node/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:971:7)
    at /Users/user/Projects/Project_node/app.js:51:7
    at Layer.handle_error (/Users/user/Projects/Project_node/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/user/Projects/Project_node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
    at /Users/user/Projects/Project_node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/user/Projects/Project_node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

**EDIT 2: Got it.  I needed to recieve the values as req.body.id, req.body.minage, etc... not as req.body[0].id.
Weird to get an error like that but that solved the error.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re seeing different behavior in postman, that’s because postman just does the `POST` directly while the browser instead does a [CORS preflight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) before trying the `POST`.

So it sounds like the request that’s causing the *“Can't set headers after they are sent”* you’re seeing is that `OPTIONS` request, not the `POST` request.

You can confirm that by sending a `OPTIONS` request with postman, and making sure to also supply an `Origin` request header as part of the request. With `curl` you can do that like this:

```
curl -X OPTIONS -i -H 'Origin: http://x.y' http://localhost:3000/user/preferences
```

That will likely produce the same 500 error you’re seeing from the browser request.

As far as how to fix it, I think there’s no way anybody else here could tell you without seeing a lot more of your server side code. But what it would seem to come down to is, somewhere in your code you have one or more places with logic for handling `OPTIONS` requests, and somewhere in that `OPTIONS`-handling code, it’s trying to send headers after they’ve already been sent.

To track down where that is, it seems like you want to look through the server logs on the server side and find any message that’s getting logged when that 500 failure occurs.

And by the way, in this case the thing that triggers the browser to do a COR preflight `OPTIONS` request to begin with is the `myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')` part.

Comment: Hi sideshow, thanks for the response.  I could be completely wrong, but that doesnt seem to be the issue.  I sent the options request through curl and got a response of 200 - which would seem to indicate all is well there... I also have multiple other API endpoints (that look pretty much exactly the same, just different stored procedure names and parameters) that work fine.  I've updated my post with the error message.  The rest of the app is pretty much a standard node installation - I havent changed much at all.

Comment: OK not sure how much the answer actually helped but I do see you from from your update to the question that you managed to track down the cause and fix it, so I’m just glad to hear you found the solution :)